# Error while compiling OpenCV with CMake in Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, c++builder

For a project, I need to use OpenCV in Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3. I found a [post](https://answers.opencv.org/question/54717/opencv-in-c-builder-rad-studio-xe7/) on the OpenCV forum about someone who compiled it. I tried to run this command in the RAD Studio command prompt:

```
cmake.exe -G"Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_OPENEXR=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF
```

But when I run `make` or `make install`, after generating the build files, I get an error:

```
Fatal F1003 C:/PROGRA~2/EMBARC~1/Studio/20.0/include/DINKUM~2\yvals.h 34: Error directive: Please use headers from dinkumware directory
```

When checking the file specified in the line, I see that the error comes from this code:

```cpp
#if !defined(__clang__)
#error Please use headers from dinkumware directory
#endif
```

First, I tried to ignore the error by not including where the error occurred, which worked for some options, but then I got an error at an option that can't be excluded.

I wanted to check if there were no other errors that would occur while trying to compile OpenCV. My guess is that because I try to use CMake for the bcc32 compiler, then there is no CLANG used and that generates the error, but the post explained above also uses bcc32 and it doesn't seem to create the same error.

Does this problem only occur in newer versions, or is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I am pretty sure OpenCV uses modern C++ syntax and won't compile with the Borland "Classic" compiler. You need to use the clang compiler. This is probably why the code includes the check for __clang___ (I think the reported error message could be more helpful though, why not say "must use Clang compiler" ?)

Comment: [bcc32](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32) is the old Borland classic compiler, it is not based on clang.  Use [bcc32c or bcc32x](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers) instead, they are both based on clang (bcc32c is command-line compatible with bcc32, whereas bcc32x is not).